# Adobe Flex: Event.COMPLETE for Image does not fire when image loaded from Bitmap

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a weird issue. I can get Event.COMPLETE to fire when I set

```
image.source = byteArray;
```

BUT

When I manipulate the byteArray - convert it to Bitmap and use image.source or image.load to load it, the bitmap gets loaded properly into the Image component; BUT Event.COMPLETE never fires. What might be wrong here? I have added an event lister for complete too! My source is as follows:

```
                var bmp:Bitmap = scaleBitmapData(bitmapData,280,220);
                imgPreview.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onPreviewImageCompleted); // never fires
                imgPreview.visible = false;
                imgPreview.load(bmp); // does not work with .source either; image is displayed but Event.Complete never fires!
```

Thanks
Subrat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the class in play here is SWFLoader (Image extends SWFLoader). If you passed in the ByteArray or a url than it adds the appropriate listener. What you've done is fed it a Bitmap, which is a display object. Here is the important code that is loading a Bitmap into an Image:

```
 else if (classOrString is DisplayObject)
 {
     contentHolder = child = DisplayObject(classOrString);
     addChild(child);
     contentLoaded();
 }
```

ByteArray:

```
else if (byteArray)
{
    loader = new FlexLoader();
    contentHolder = child = loader;
    addChild(child);

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.COMPLETE, contentLoaderInfo_completeEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.INIT, contentLoaderInfo_initEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, contentLoaderInfo_ioErrorEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.UNLOAD, contentLoaderInfo_unloadEventHandler);

    // if loaderContext null, it will use default, which is AppDomain
    // of child of Loader's context
    loader.loadBytes(byteArray, loaderContext);
}
```

a url:

```
else if (url)
{
    // Create an instance of the Flash Player Loader class to do all the work
    loader = new FlexLoader();
    contentHolder = child = loader;

    // addChild needs to be called before load()
    addChild(loader);

    // Forward the events from the Flash Loader to anyone
    // who has registered as an event listener on this Loader.
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.COMPLETE, contentLoaderInfo_completeEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, contentLoaderInfo_httpStatusEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.INIT, contentLoaderInfo_initEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, contentLoaderInfo_ioErrorEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.OPEN, contentLoaderInfo_openEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, contentLoaderInfo_progressEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, contentLoaderInfo_securityErrorEventHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(
        Event.UNLOAD, contentLoaderInfo_unloadEventHandler); 
...[this goes on for awhile]
```

So you get the gist here. Don't convert it to a Bitmap and you'll get your complete event. You could also add ADDED_TO_STAGE to your Bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joel. I am loading the image from FileReference.data ByteArray using FileReference.load, so I have no choice but to use ByteArray. However, I listened to the ADDED_TO_STAGE event on the bitmap instead and it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: you can use the bitmapdata with image.load and it will fire the complete event. Casting it to a Bitmap is where it just adds it as a child instead.

Comment: Subrat Basnet! you are totally correct in the case "I listened to the ADDED_TO_STAGE event on the bitmap instead". When you required to use Bitmap, but not ByteArray.